# Facebook "og:url" directions cause clickable image to link to the my old page

Tags: facebook, cdn, canonical-link

Here's my situation.  To handle occasional spikes in traffic I got a CDN.

Google says that I should indicate the preferred URL using the rel="canonical" link, so I add:

rel="canonical" href="http://cdn.example.com/cats.html"

But it seems that causes me to lose my Facebook likes on my button on my page so I follow Facebook's "How to move a page to a different URL" advice (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#moving-urls) and create an og:url to the OLD page to keep the likes.
"meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/cats.html"

So far so good.  I change my button so that shares go to my new page, my likes magically appear and all is right with the world, but . . .

. . . whenever I post a link to my page using the new location (http://cdn.example.com/cats.html) on Facebook the link comes out ok but the clickable image beneath the my post links to the old page!

So my question is, two fold 1) is there any way to fix it so the clickable image on FB goes to the new page, and if not 2) am I going to get an SEO hit for my 280K likes showing on the button going down to 20?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked by debugging the URL using facebook [Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) as it might be due to cache.

Comment: I did use it.  The only thing of note that happened is it gave a warning that the canonical link was not the same as the og:url link.  Which must be the case if you follow their directions to get your likes back.   If I make the canonical link the same as the og:url link the image will point to the correct new page (the cdn page) but then I lose all my old likes.  Seems like a bug in their set up.